# Commerce 2.x Taxes missing

Tags: commerce

I installed commerce 2.x and all seemed well. I have recently noticed there's no sign of any settings to configure taxes. When first setting up a store the taxes section (see image) wasn't visible as an option.  My "vendor/commerceguys" folder contains zone, intl, enum and addressing.

Do I have to run the composer command "composer require "drupal/tax"" or something? To install commerce in the first place I ran "composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev" as instructed on the drupal commerce site so puzzled no tax setting are available? Also where does composer manager come into it, is this something I need to proceed?

Thanks for any help
[image: Tax settings option]

Comment: Composer Manager is not used anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Taxes doesn't exist.

Longer answer:
Taxes have not yet been implemented for Drupal commerce 2.x. You can follow along in the issue queue, git or IRC if you want to track the progress.

One of the relevant issue would be [Tax data model](https://www.drupal.org/node/2841016).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback, much appreciated! So in the short term what tax system should I put in place in order to launch a commerce 2.x site in the next month or so? would I need a service like Avalara? I'm only wanting to sell in the UK initially. If there's a solution you could recommend that would be great! Many Thanks

Comment: Avalara is good for sales tax, but since you're in the UK, your products probably have one or two VAT rates, and that's it. You can hardcode those, implement them in an order processor like https://github.com/mglaman/commerce_demo/blob/master/src/OrderProcessor/ApplyTaxAdjustments.php does.

Comment: Great thanks! I'll give it a whirl, its about time I got my hands dirty with my first bit of coding, I've read enough theory about it, its time to try. Regards!

Comment: Is it still in development ? I tried to create a tax but I can't find how to apply it on a product.